# how to use struts <s:iterator> and <s:if> together?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have lists of objects named `allAlbums` and `allPhotos`. Now I want to show all photos in each album so I used the following method. My code is

```
<s:iterator value="allAlbums">
  <s:iterator value="allPhotos">
    <s:if test="%{#allAlbums.albumid == #allPhotos.albumid}">
      <s:property value="photourl"/>
    </s:if>
  </s:iterator>                             
</s:iterator>
```

But it is not working. Any suggestion what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why can't you try with this in query. U should sent only the photos that has same album id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that both of your object have appropriate getters/setters, then you can use feature provided by OGNL called projection.

```
<s:iterator value="allAlbums" var="album">
  <s:iterator value="allPhotos.{? #this.albumid == #album.albumid}">
      <s:property value="photourl"/>
  </s:iterator>                             
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are referencing wrong object. Define a `var` attribute for the records you would reference and reference it instead.

```
<s:iterator var="album" value="allAlbums">
  <s:iterator var="photo" value="allPhotos">
    <s:if test="#album.id == #photo.albumId">
      <s:property value="photoUrl"/>
    </s:if>
  </s:iterator>                             
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: @bril what's the data type of id in album?

Comment: with absence of of the sources the code posted is correct, it depends on how you will apply it in your case.

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV: Integer type